# Variable scope in block

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift and since there is now a compiler available on Linux I installed it and tested some programs. And there is one thing I don't understand. Why does this contrived example give an error during the compilation?

```
var x = 86;

if x <= 32 {
    ++x;
    print(x);
} else if x >= 86 {
    x = 2 * x;
    print(x);
    var x = false;
    if !x {
        print(x);
    }
} else {
    --x;
    print(x);
}
print(x);
```

error:

```
15.swift:7:5: error: use of local variable 'x' before its declaration
    x = 2 * x;
    ^
15.swift:9:9: note: 'x' declared here
    var x = false;
        ^
15.swift:7:13: error: use of local variable 'x' before its declaration
    x = 2 * x;
            ^
15.swift:9:9: note: 'x' declared here
    var x = false;
        ^
15.swift:8:11: error: use of local variable 'x' before its declaration
    print(x);
          ^
15.swift:9:9: note: 'x' declared here
    var x = false;
        ^
```

Why is this like this? I mean, it's not magic, corresponding example in C++ works as one could imagine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x = 86;
    if (x <= 32) {
        ++x;
        cout << x << endl;
    } else if (x >= 86) {
        x = x * 2;
        bool x = false;
        if (!x) {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    } else {
        --x;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is: did I just find a bug in Swift compiler or it's just that Swift uses some less intuitive scope semantics? If it does, where can I read about it? Seems so strange..

Comment: I think that C++ example suffers from serious readability problems that could lead to hard to find bugs because `x` refers to completely different things within the same context. I don't know when that's ever a good idea to use this pattern. The Swift warnings are much better, IMHO.

Comment: But these are not only warnings. Swift refuses to execute my code. And I'm wondering it that's ok. I know that C++ example is not a good code. But that's not the point. The point is that I think I should be able to redeclare a variable at a different scope - in a block. It works that way in C++ an I'm sure it's more intuitive for many programmers.

Comment: This is kinda strange, because it compiles on Xcode. Maybe Linux bug?

Comment: No, it does not compile with Xcode (7.2).

Comment: It does in a project, but not in playground :o (also 7.2)

Comment: I guess the compiler notices the declaration of the local `boolean` variable `x` and assumes that the `x` before the declaration is locally too. Because there cannot be two variables with the same name and different type in the same local scope the developer might be mistaken. Apart from that it's bad programming habit – and very confusing – to declare local variables with the same name as preceding variables in a wider scope.

Comment: I think that (in contrast to C/C++), the scope of a variable is the *entire code block* in which it is defined.

Comment: This code works, even in a Playground if you put it inside of a function.

Comment: @vacawama: That is interesting (and my last comment is wrong). So this is something special about re-declaring variables declared at the global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should works for you. (a) you are not able to redeclare the variable in part of current scope, (b) Bool and Int types are not interchangeable in Swift

```
var x = 86;

if x <= 32 {
    ++x;
    print(x)
} else if x >= 86 {
    x = 2 * x
    print(x)
    var xb = false
    if !xb {
        print(x)
    }
} else {
    --x
    print(x)
}
print(x)
```

this is the base of your trouble

```
var x = 1
var x = true // error: invalid redeclaration of 'x'
```

@xan is not erratic. you can not redeclare the variable. you can declare the new one for the whole semantic unit.

```
var x = 1
for i in 1...3 {
    var x = 10
    print(i,x) // 1 10, 2 10, 3 10
}
print(x) // 1
```

to better understand Swift behavior and differences to C , look at this

```
var x = 1
repeat {
    var x = 10 //
    print(x--) // 10 10
    print(++x) // 10 10
    x++
    print(x)   // 11 11
} while x-- > 0
print(x) // -1
```

Comment: That's not totally true. You can declare variables with the same name and different type locally. Prove it by deleting the `x = 2 * x` line and move the `var x = false` line above the first `print` line both within the `else` scope.

Comment: @vadian, exactly. And I know this code can be fixed, but that's not the point. The point is semantics, which apparently is very erratic. As observed sometimes we can redeclare a variable in block and sometimes not. It confuses me that my example does not compile.

Comment: @vadian please, see first what the guy is trying to do, before complain. and check properly what i wrote ... (a)

Comment: @xan this works as expected, in OSX and Linux, at both platforms exactly as described by apple in documentation. you better to read first something about Swift and not talk about bugs.

Comment: @user3441734, you have a point in your update with "the whole semantic unit". Thanks! Although typo in comment, should be: // 1 10, 2 10, 3 10

Comment: @xan, you are right, i will update my typo. i am sorry for this!

Comment: @user3441734, and can you point me this documentation describing this semantics? Because yes, I read it and still found this example confusing. Docs are not very thorough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98487/discussion-between-user3441734-and-xan).